# Is CancellationToken available in ASP.NET Core ActionFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I could inject `CancellationToken` into **ASP.NET Core** action method, but I would instead prefer to work with it using action filter. How to get access to cancellation token while implementing  `IAsyncActionFilter`? My method should not have it as a parameter then.

Comment: @madreflection Please see an example [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/).

Comment: @madreflection It makes very much sense to inject/use CancellationToken values and supply such down through call-stacks. They contain “internal magic” to all wire to the same CancellationTokenSource, as an example; not so primitive as an integer, eg. Being a struct is a separate discussion point. (The injected value would be discreet per request or as required, and usually not a singleton: again, this is a separate discussion as to the particular injection method and naught to do with value types.)

Comment: I think that _"inject"_ is a wrong word here. Instead you may say _"I could **pass** `CancellationToken` into ASP.NET Core action method..."_

Comment: @vasily.sib I do not think that I could pass something I do not have. `CancellationToken` is being instantiated and provided by `interface injection` as an action method argument by ASP.NET Core the same way as some IoC container could do `constructor injection` of other dependencies it is responsible for.

Comment: @DmitryNogin, trust me, you have it. As from your link: _"MVC will automatically bind any `CancellationToken` parameters in an action method to the `HttpContext.RequestAborted` token, using the `CancellationTokenModelBinder`. This model binder is registered automatically when **you** call `services.AddMvc()` (or `services.AddMvcCore()`) in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`."_

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, that could work. But as I stated above at the end of the original question: I actually would not like to have such a CancellationToken parameter in every method. I am looking for a way to access and process token by the action filter only. (It is supposed to work with [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230014/operation-cancellation)).

Comment: As from your link, you need to get `context.HttpContext.RequestAborted` token within your `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)` method

Comment: @vasily.sib Perfect, thanks! Shame on me :) I just googled it over the course of the discussion to have a code example for  sharing and did not actually read it :) Could you please post your answer below so I could accept it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You already post [a link](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/) to a very good article, which contains a small hint where you can get this token.

> MVC will automatically bind any `CancellationToken` parameters in an action method to the **HttpContext.RequestAborted** token, using the `CancellationTokenModelBinder`.

So, all you have to do is acquire that token in your action filter:

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var cancellationToken = context.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```